# Reactive Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, system.reactive

Is it possible to apply reactive framework (Rx) in MVC application? or is it applicable for WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to use it in any part of .NET it is especially useful when there is some user interaction. With MVC or any server side technology, there is no user interaction. Each request is handled from beginning to end. So the usefulness is limited.

Comment: oh ! Now I can understand it.Thank you.

Comment: I disagree - it can be very useful in ASP.NET where you can for example use it as a lightweight message bus.  It is also a very easy way to handle interval tasks, retries etc, all sorts of things that aren't necessarily related to user interaction.

Comment: @MartinErnst: Would you be so kind to post this as an answer and include some examples? It would be great to see this in action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The technologies are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree. That might have been true for the web in the 90s, but the web certainly doesn't work like that anymore.

Here's a hint: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/10/signalr-rx-framework/